# ld: framework not found Stripe for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, stripe-payments

I have an iOS component which relies on the [Stripe iOS SDK](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios), Project A. I included the Stripe SDK in  Project A in Xcode and it compiles fine.

However, I'm building another project in Xcode which relies on this component, Project B. I added Project A to Project B's libraries. Project A relies on project B but does not rely directly on the Stripe SDK.

Now, whenever I try to compile Project B, I get this error:

`ld: framework not found Stripe for architecture x86_64`

This line (inside Project A) seems to trigger the error:

`#import <Stripe/Stripe.h>`

Xcode has no trouble finding `Stripe.h`. I tried adding the Stripe SDK directly to Project B as well. I've double and triple-checked the Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries section for all targets (`Stripe.framework` is listed).

I added the Stripe framework manually, so then I also tried adding it with Cocoapods instead, but that also didn't work.

Please help!

Here's the project structure for Project B ("example"), with Project A ("RCTFBLogin") below it.

[image]

Here's the full error:

[image]

I'm using Xcode 7.2 and the most recent version of the Stripe SDK (6.0.0). The same Stripe framework code works fine in another project.

Thanks.

Update: I added "`$(SRCROOT)/../..`" (since Project B lives two folders deep inside Project A) to "Framework Search Paths" under Build Settings -> "Search Paths" for the Project B target and it began compiling successfully.  However, I now get this error when running:

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/rettig/wip/react-native-facebook-login.2/Stripe.framework/Stripe', framework linker option at /Users/rettig/wip/react-native-facebook-login.2/Stripe.framework/Stripe is not a dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Stripe", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRCTFBLogin.a(RCTFBLogin.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to do two things to get this working:

1. Add "$(SRCROOT)/../.." (since Project B lives two folders deep inside Project A) to "Framework Search Paths" under Build Settings -> "Search Paths" for the Project B target.
2. Add the Stripe SDK to Project B's frameworks as well.  This second step in particular surprised me because Project B does not rely directly upon Stripe.

Answer (score 13):

I was seeing this same issue with another framework while running my test target. I had to add the framework to my *test target* (not only my normal target) under `Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries` section.

Carthage has more info about the issue I saw: https://github.com/carthage/carthage#adding-frameworks-to-unit-tests-or-a-framework

Answer (score 11):

### Did you run into this issue when you ran your test cases?

So this is how my podfile looks like:

```
def shared_pods
    pod ‘GoogleMaps', '~> 1.13.0'
    pod ‘SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3.2'
    pod ‘Alamofire', '~> 3.2.1'
    pod ‘MGSwipeTableCell’
end

target 'projectName' do
   shared_pods
end
```

So then I added this to podfile:

```
target ‘ProjectTests’ do
    pod ‘Nimble’, ‘~> 4.0.0’
    pod ’Quick’
end
```

What I also needed to do was:

```
target ‘ProjectTests’ do
    shared_pods // I needed to add this line as well. Since this line included the needed 'MGSwipeTableCell' framework 
    pod ‘Nimble’, ‘~> 4.0.0’
    pod ’Quick’
end
```

So a possible reason would be that in your podfile you didn't add them correctly, just be sure that the framework is added into the necessary targets.

Comment: man one hour I'm searching for a solution. I deleted all my derived data, clean my project more than once and tried to link my testtarget manually. work for me - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Noticed this problem while switching some dependencies from pods to carthage.  Similar to Honey's answer, I was able to get around this error modifying the podfile.

Turns out all I had to add was the test target. Then run 'pod install', and it will link your test target to your the frameworks generated by your pods.

```
target 'Project' do
  use_frameworks!

  //pods here normally

  target 'ProjectTests' do
   //nothing in here
  end
end
```