# Why does my iOS project with Cocoapods try (and fails) to build on a x86_64 architecture?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcodebuild, google-places

I got the following error testing my test target in Xcode:

```
ld: framework not found GoogleMapsBase for architecture x86_64
```

My project is an iOS project so I don't really understand why it builds with a x86_64 architecture. When examining my Pods project, the build settings feature the following settings:

- Base SDK: No SDK (Latest macOS)
- Supported Platforms: macOS
- Valid architectures: i386 x86_64

My Podfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Foo' do
  use_frameworks!
  ...
  pod 'GooglePlaces', '2.0.1'
  ...    

  target 'FooTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'Quick', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'Nimble', '~> 5.0'
  end
end
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

UPDATE: cf [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38298354/455016) for the answer of a similar question that helped me fix my issue.

Comment: It's actually more a duplicate of another question where this answer helped : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38298354/455016

Comment: I fixed my issue by adding GooglePlaces and GoogleMapsBase frameworks in the "Link Binary with Libraries" of my target test. It sounds like a misconfiguration of the pods to me.

Answer (score 0):

A question. Do you literally included `...` in your podfile? Or is it you are omitting other pods with this sign?

Now, the simpler edition of your podfile would be like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Foo' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'GooglePlaces', '2.0.1' 

end

target 'FooTests' do

    pod 'Quick', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'Nimble', '~> 5.0'

end
```

This should work. Let us know what you got.

Comment: :) Of course, "..." means I don't mention other pods :)