# iOS build error: framework not found FileProvider for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to build an Ionic 3 app for iOS and I keep getting this error when building both with Xcode and on Ionic Pro.

When using Xcode I get:

```
[x] ld: framework not found FileProvider for architecture x86_64
```

On Ionic Pro I get:

```
[x] ld: framework not found FileProvider for architecture armv7
```

This same project already builds and works on Android.

Comment: how are you adding framework? By pods or embedding it from build setting?Is this link help full-: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798741/ld-framework-not-found-stripe-for-architecture-x86-64

Comment: @TusharSharma I never even added it, I don't think I even need it. The project is generated by the Ionic CLI. I've used Ionic a lot before and never had this problem.

Comment: Find a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @MatthewHarrison Sorry, yes. Turns out I just had to update Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, just had to update Xcode. That doesn't really explain why it wasn't working on Ionic Pro though. But it worked fine in Xcode after updating.